# Which language is better for process streaming using Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am a little confused. Can someone help or guide me that which language (Python, JAVA, C#) is better for process streaming using Flink. Which language has more support or whose apis are more mature. Anyone please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java API for Flink is the most mature and best supported, with Scala coming in a close second. Other JVM languages (e.g. Kotlin) can be used, but have no explicit support.

Over the past several releases Python support has been under active development (see [PyFlink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/python/installation.html)), but it still lags behind the JVM languages, except in the case of the Stateful Functions API, where it has first class support for writing remote functions. Other non-JVM languages can also be used for implementing remote stateful functions: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-statefun-docs-stable/sdk/external.html.

[SQL](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/sql) is also very well supported by Flink, in its niche. C# is not supported.

Comment: with new Stateful function version v3.0.0, Java support is also available https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-statefun-docs-release-3.0/docs/sdk/java/